# How can my expect script set params from my config file

Tags: linux, expect

I'm writing a expect file to scp file automatically. But what I do every time is input the host and password in the terminal.Another way is set the pass word in hard code way. I wanna whether there is a way to read the config from a located file on my laptop. And it will be better when I share my script with others.

Comment: You have gotten some downvotes because your question is too broad and there's no apparent effort to solve it yourself. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and other questions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1):

First, see if you can set us password-less connection to the server (contact the server administrator, and see your `ssh-keygen` and `ssh-copy-id` man pages)

Otherwise, writing login credentials to disc is bad security, but sometimes unavoidable. Make sure you give the file no read/write permissions for others (`chmod 600 config_file`)

Suppose you want to have a config file with these contents:

```
set host hostname
set user username
set pass "user password"
```

Then, you script can simply `source` the file to set those variables in your Tcl interpreter.

For safety, in case that file gets compromised with some evil commands, you can use a Tcl "safe interpreter"

```tcl
interp create -safe safeInterp
safeInterp invokehidden source $configFile
# extract the variables from the safe interp
lassign [safeInterp eval {list $host $user $pass}] host user pass

spawn scp $user@$host:/path/to/remote/file /local/file
...
```